# Choose alternate value in array

Tags: c#

I have a time slot as such:

```
TimeSpan Midnight = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
List<DateTime> Timeslot = new List<DateTime>();
Timeslot.Add(BookingStart)
Timeslot.Add(BookingEnd)
Timeslot.Add(breakstart1)
Timeslot.Add(breakEnd1)
Timeslot.Add(breakstart2)
Timeslot.Add(breakEnd2)
Timeslot.Add(breakstart3)
Timeslot.Add(breakEnd3)

for (int i = 1; i <= Timeslot.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (Timeslot[0] != Timeslot[1])
    {
        if ((Timeslot[i].TimeOfDay < Midnight) &&
            (dutyEnd.TimeOfDay >= Midnight))
        {
            BookedHours = Midnight - Timeslot[i].TimeOfDay;
            // if i value is one then i want get the value like
            // BookedHours = Midnight - Timeslot[i,End].TimeOfDay;
            // BookedHours = Midnight - Timeslot[breakEnd1].TimeOfDay;
        }
    }
}
```

what am trying to do here is if my "i" value is "one" then want to get the `breakEnd1` value.

let me explain it little clear here

i have one booking for eg

Booking start at : 18.00 and Booking End @ (next day):7.00

I have three breaks in between,those breaks are follows
(breakstart1) starts at : 20.00
(breakEnd1) end at : 21.00
(breakstart2) : 24.00
(breakEnd2):01.00
(breakstart3):03.00
(breakEnd3):04.00

now what am trying to do here is

```
if midnight is not null and timeslot[i,end]<midnight then
am calculating booked hours like = midnight-timeslot[i,end]
```

is that make sense now ?

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < Timeslot.Count; i++)`

Comment: you just want to calculate the booked hours of SOMETHING with given BREAKS or given BOOKINGS? (it's an inversion logic then)...
it should sum up all booked hours between/over the timeslots, right? which .net-version do you use?

Comment: @Usher could you reformulate your question? What you are trying to achieve is not clear at all.

Comment: @TheHe,yep exactly. am using .net 4

Comment: don't know what the logic with MIDNIGHT tell's us, but i'll provide an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var bookingStartsAndEnds = new List<DateTime>()
                                           {
                                               DateTime.Parse("1999-02-01 13:50:00"),
                                               DateTime.Parse("1999-02-03 13:50:00"),
                                               DateTime.Parse("1999-02-04 13:05:00"),
                                               DateTime.Parse("1999-02-04 13:15:00"),
                                           };

            var bookedHours = bookingStartsAndEnds
                // order by the date ascending
                .OrderBy(dt => dt)
                // select only the "firsts" of the tuples
                .Where((dt, i) => i%2 == 0)
                // select the first + the next
                .Select((dt, i) => Tuple.Create<DateTime, DateTime?>(dt, bookingStartsAndEnds.ElementAtOrDefault((i*2) + 1)))
                // filter not-matching-end (the list must contain even number of items only!)
                .Where(t => t.Item2 != null)
                // calculate the time-difference between end-date and start-date and get all hours
                .Select(t => (t.Item2.Value - t.Item1).TotalHours)
                // sum them up
                .Sum(); 

            Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00} hours dude! this will be expensive...", bookedHours);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not at all clear what you are trying to do. 
This does not make much sense:

```
if (Timeslot[0] != Timeslot[1]);
```

But I suspect that what you are trying to do is to focus on not the items in the list themselves, but on the consecutive pairs (Item1 with Item2, Item2 with Item3,Item3 with Item4 etc).

One way to achieve this would be to merge Timeslot with an offset version of itself like this:

```
foreach (var timewindow in Timeslot.Zip(Timeslot.Skip(1),Tuple.Create))
{
     Console.WriteLine(String.Format("handling duration from {0} to {1}",timewindow.Item1,timewindow.Item2));
}
```

Comment: .zip is highskill-elegance ;) but the resulting list will contain 3 items instead of two, because only the "left-side" is shiftet ONE item...